# SSRS Report parameter drop down along with user search option possibility

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

SSRS Report parameter drop down along with user search(data key-in/type-in) capability.
Is it possible to search for category on report parameter, when you have too many categories in the drop down menu. I know i can create additional report parameter to filter on drop down but i want to have free text/search option available on the report parameter so that users can either type/key-in category or choose from drop down menu?

Is this possible? If so how can i achieve this.
Thanks!

Comment: how about you have both of them as parameters with the free text search as an optional parameter?  something along the lines of  where (@category = sometable.column or sometable.colum like '%'+@category_search+'%'

Comment: Is it possible to search/filter on the report parameter(with multiple values drop down). I'm talking about one single report parameter where you can search and choose from the list same time. I know how to do this with two parameters but not with single report parameter. If possible then how.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do what you want. Once a drop down list is populated, then you are unable to enter anything in that list manually. Hence my suggestion of using a separate parameter for anything you want searched manually